# What is wrong with this C++ code from URI Online Judge?

Tags: c++

Can you please help me to find the wrong in this C++ code for a problem in URI Online Judge... this is the problem:
https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1038
and this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int Code,Qau;
double F;

int main () {
    cin >> Code >> Qau;
    if (Code==1) {
        F=4.00*Qau;
        cout <<"Total: R$ ";
        printf ("%.2lf\n",F);
    } else if (Code==2) {
        F=4.50*Qau;
        cout <<"Total: R$ ";
        printf ("%.2lf\n",F);
    } else if (Code==3) {
        F=5.00*Qau;
        cout <<"Total: R$ ";
        printf ("%.2lf\n",F);
    } else if (Code==4) {
        F=2.00*Qau;
        cout <<"Total: R$ ";
        printf ("%.2lf\n",F);
    } else if (Code==5) {
        F=1.50*Qau;
        cout <<"Total: R$ ";
        ("%.2lf",F); 
        cout <<endl;
    } 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1st of all: The formatting looks horrible.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour, and what is the behaviour that you get instead?

Answer (score 0):

In the fifth block you forgot to use printf there are just braces with the expression but no command itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are specifying can be solved simply with this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float val[] = { 4, 4.5, 5, 2, 1.5 };
    int X, Y;
    cin >> X >> Y;
    cout << "Total: R$ " << setprecision(2) << fixed << val[X - 1] * Y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

or simplifying your code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int Code, Qau;
    double F;
    cin >> Code >> Qau;
    if (Code == 1) F = 4.00;
    else if (Code == 2) F = 4.50;
    else if (Code == 3) F = 5.00;
    else if (Code == 4) F = 2.00;
    else if (Code == 5) F = 1.50;
    printf("Total: R$ %.2lf\n", F * Qau);
    return 0;
}
```